# What's happens in Ruby and Python? Why the variable wil be nil in if block in ruby ,but undefined in python?

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, ruby

This question already has an answer [Confusion with the assignment operation inside a falsy `if` block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15183576/confusion-with-the-assignment-operation-inside-a-falsy-if-block)

```
  if false
      y = 'hi'
   end

  puts y
```

In ruby y has been "defined" in the if block,it will be nil(why?). Remove that block and this gives an error.

But, in python

```
 if False:
   y = 'hi'

 print y
```

It will gives an error.

What's happens in Ruby and Python?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15042691/scope-in-ruby-and-python

Comment: Not a duplicate, this has nothing to do with scope

Comment: You have two questions here, so you should ask two questions. Actually, you shouldn't, because I know for a fact that the one about Ruby has already been asked and answered, and I strongly suspect that the same is true about the Python question as well.

Comment: Thx,I try to find the answers , but I can't find it.Can you post the url?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15183576/confusion-with-the-assignment-operation-inside-the-fallacy-if-block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yukihiro Matsumoto [states](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/155673#685906)

> The local variables are created in compile time [...]

That's why `y` is defined in Ruby, whereas Python uses a dictionary to store local variables in runtime. This can be accessed directly through `locals()` as well.

The Ruby part also came up [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19323864/3385212).

Comment: Python local variables are also recognized at compile time. The difference is that the name itself must actually be bound at run time, and in the question it is not.

Comment: @chepner [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15183576/confusion-with-the-assignment-operation-inside-a-falsy-if-block)